# Creating an addition table using nothing but for loops on eclipse with Python

Tags: python, eclipse, addition

This is what it should look like:

```
Enter start value: 1
Enter end value: 5

Addition Table

          1    2    3    4    5
      -------------------------
    1|    2    3    4    5    6
    2|    3    4    5    6    7
    3|    4    5    6    7    8
    4|    5    6    7    8    9
    5|    6    7    8    9   10
```

This is what I have so far:

```
start = int(input("Enter start value: "))
end = int(input("Enter end value: "))
increment = int(input("Enter an increment value: "))

limit = end + 1  # So that limit can be inclusive in the following loop

# So that we can have a space between "Enter end value" and the results.
print()
total = 0
for top in range(start, limit, increment):
    print("    {}".format(top), end="")
    total = total + 1

print()
print("    {}".format("-" * (total * 6)), end="")
print()
for horizontal in range(start, limit, increment):
    print("{}|    {}    {}    {}    {}    {}".format(horizontal, horizontal + increment, horizontal +
                                                     increment * 2, horizontal + increment * 3, horizontal + increment * 4, horizontal + increment * 5))
```

*** PLEASE NOTE ****

I am required to use nothing but for loops. No while loops, or any other method. Strictly for loops and if statements if required. I'm really stuck for this program. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you get ? btw. this problem has nothing to do with eclipse.

Comment: inside `for horizontal` you could use another `for` loop to display any number of  columns.

Comment: you can use ie. `{:>7}` instead of `{}` and spaces. More: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @furas Do you mind showing me exactly how I could do that? I've tried but obviously wasn't successful

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `for` loop inside other `for` loop to create different number of columns.

Besides you can use `string formatting` ([PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)) if it is allowed in the task.

```
start = int(input("Enter start value: "))
end = int(input("Enter end value: "))
increment = int(input("Enter an increment value: "))

limit = end + 1  # So that limit can be inclusive in the following loop

# So that we can have a space between "Enter end value" and the results.
print()

total = 0
print("   |", end="")
for top in range(start, limit, increment):
    print("{:>6}".format(top), end="")
    total += 1
print()

print("---+{}".format("-" * (total*6)))

for y in range(start, limit, increment):
    print("{:>3}|".format(y), end="")
    for x in range(start, limit, increment):
        print("{:>6}".format(x+y), end="")
    print()
```

Result

```
Enter start value: 1
Enter end value: 15
Enter an increment value: 2

   |     1     3     5     7     9    11    13    15
---+------------------------------------------------
  1|     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16
  3|     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18
  5|     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20
  7|     8    10    12    14    16    18    20    22
  9|    10    12    14    16    18    20    22    24
 11|    12    14    16    18    20    22    24    26
 13|    14    16    18    20    22    24    26    28
 15|    16    18    20    22    24    26    28    30
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured it out doing much more for loops, but I like yours better. Thanks again.